# Изменить цвет вкладки TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms

Имею WinForms элемент управления TabControl. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить цвет именно самой вкладки (когда она еще не «нажата»)?

Comment: Web? Win Forms? Wtf?

Answer (score 2):

Выставляешь свойство `DrawMode` в `OwnerDrawFixed` и потом обрабатываешь событие `DrawItem` как-то так

```
private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.SetClip(e.Bounds);
        string text = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text;
        SizeF sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString(text, e.Font);

        bool bSelected = (e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected;
        using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(bSelected ? SystemColors.Highlight : SystemColors.Control))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, e.Bounds);

        using (SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(bSelected ? SystemColors.HighlightText : SystemColors.ControlText))
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, b, e.Bounds.X + 2, e.Bounds.Y + (e.Bounds.Height - sz.Height) / 2);

        if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == e.Index)
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();

        e.Graphics.ResetClip();
    }
```

Comment: Определенно, телепаты среди нас :)

Comment: По постановке вопроса становится очевидным, что вопрос по WinForms :) Но благодарю за комплимент